# How to check undefined variable in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, stack, undefined

I have this code in my project in c++ :

```
class StackNode{
    public:

        StackNode(){
            this->varName = NULL;
            this->down = NULL;
        }

        char * varName;

        StackNode * down;

    };


class Stack{
    public:
        StackNode * head;

        Stack(){
            this->head == NULL;
        }

        bool IsEmpty(StackNode * node){
            if(node == NULL){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
};
..
..
.. 
    void ST::localVariableStack(StNode * node){
        Stack * stack = new Stack();
        StNode * temp = node;
        checkUndeclaredVarible(temp, stack);
        while (temp->left){
            checkUndeclaredVarible(temp->left, stack);
            temp = temp->left;
        }
    }

    void ST::checkUndeclaredVarible(StNode * node, Stack * stack){
        if(ifInteger(node)){
            if(node->declared){
                stack->AddUnite(node->VarName);
            }else{
                if(!isItExiteInStack(node, stack)){
                    this->errRecovery->errQ->enqueue(node->lineno, node->colno, "Undeclared Variable : ", node->VarName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    bool ST::isItExiteInStack(StNode * node, Stack * stack){
        StackNode * temp = new StackNode();
        temp = stack->head;
        while(!(stack->IsEmpty(temp))){
            if(strcmp(temp->varName, node->VarName) == 0){
                return true;
            }
            temp = temp->down;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The problem is when I call `stack->isempty(temp)` the temp object go to the `isempty` function, in the situation that temp is empty although there are a default constructor. When check `(node == NULL)` in `isempty` function it take a `false` and return `false` rather than `true`, so after this function will break because he act like non empty object.

Comment: Please only tag the language you are using.

Comment: @Ron: I'm sure it's deliberately ironic that capitalisation wasn't appropriate there? ;)

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. It might be a [rule of 3/5/0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) violation problem, it might be an initialization problem, it could be something else. Please share a [MCVE].

Comment: It seems you only ever use a `Stack` to call it's members and those member don't seem to operate on the instance they belong to. Perhaps you meant to use static member functions or free functions instead? In addition, c++ does not automatically delete `new`ed objects. I see a lot of `new` but no `delete`.

Comment: ST is another class that have object of stack , the problem is when "StNode * temp = node;" the temp now is empty but when its check in the isempty function "if(node == NULL)" , here node as temp, it must be node to be a null , but it doesnt go inside this if , and return false, ((( its not false, its true case the object is empty , i am sorry its hard to explain but , i am here if there are somthing not clear

Comment: Wouldn't that be something easy to debug? What's the actual value of the node check in `isEmpty`?

Comment: the debug tell me that the object is not null, but his element is <unable to read memory>